# hardware requirements for eclipse and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, memory, hardware

i'm a sysad by trade, but recently i've been playing around with Java development, particularly web/servlets, just so that i can understand half of what our developers keep babbling on about :D i lacked this foresight when i bought a Dell Inspiron 11z late last year --Intel Atom CPU, 2GB RAM, mainly just for remote access/troubleshooting. Deploying a simple "Hello World" app using eclipse to a locally installed Tomcat server wasn't a pleasant experience.

i'm planning to do a RAM upgrade, will 4GB RAM be enough? i'm doing this mainly for learning so i really don't need bleeding edge tech.

Or should i look into Resin, JBoss, which hopefully can live with less RAM?

tia

Comment: The more memory the better.

Comment: Tomcat memory requirements depend on what you are going to run in Tomcat.  I've seen references to 256M as a minimum recommendation.  1Mb or more is recommended for Eclipse.  But I'd go for as much memory as you can afford.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss will need *more* RAM than tomcat. 4GB is sufficient for most tasks when developing in  Eclipse and targeting tomcat, but in general the more RAM the merrier.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is the lightest web server you can have . So, if you have issue in running Tomcat, you will have issues with all other servers.if your planning for 4GB of RAM, I can say that you can  have multiple application server running at the same time . Am using 3GB of RAM and have Tomcat, WebLogic and JBoss everything is working fine. WebLogic is little bit slow an consumes more amount of RAM ( But it is one of the powerful Application Server in the market ).

```
   With 4GB of RAM, you can run multiple application at the same time ( I Guarantee )
```

So, for 4GB everything should go smooth.

Best of luck and enjoy programming.